# Stuck at Ubuntu login screen

Tags: login, lightdm

When I try to log in to my account the screen turns black for a second then goes back to the login screen. Apparently this is a fairly common problem but nothing I've tried from past questions on this site has worked so far.

What I've tried:

Using gdm instead of lightdm

sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get update

Restoring .bashrc to its default version

chown username:username .Xauthority

Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Creating a new login account (it just does the same thing)

Things that may or may not be helpful:

When I Cntl+Alt+F2 and do the textual login, I get a bunch of errors:

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
* /bin/lesspipe
* usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because 'usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the 
PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH
environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname/'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH  
environment variable.
uname: command not found
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH 
environment variable.
sed: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH 
environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

I cannot use most of the commands like ls and sudo until I export /bin and /usr/bin to the path.

When I do "ls -ltr" in /var/log, the last log files modified are:

syslog
wtmp

auth.log

lastlog

Xorg.0.log

lightdm (directory)

Xorg.0.log.old

I couldn't find any obvious error messages in any of them.

Can anyone help me to diagnose the problem?

Edit: Here is auth.log:

```
    Jun 21 13:36:25 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sshd[551]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jun 21 13:36:25 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sshd[551]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jun 21 13:36:35 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jun 21 13:36:35 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jun 21 13:36:42 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "melissa"
Jun 21 13:36:43 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 dbus[827]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.32" (uid=104 pid=1715 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.16" (uid=0 pid=1233 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Jun 21 13:36:47 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 dbus[827]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.40" (uid=104 pid=1831 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.16" (uid=0 pid=1233 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Jun 21 13:36:50 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
Jun 21 13:36:50 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user melissa by (uid=0)
Jun 21 13:36:50 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jun 21 13:36:50 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user melissa
Jun 21 13:36:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jun 21 13:36:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jun 21 13:36:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "melissa"
Jun 21 13:36:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 dbus[827]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.47" (uid=104 pid=2010 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.16" (uid=0 pid=1233 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Jun 21 13:37:01 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 login[1034]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user melissa by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jun 21 13:38:30 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo:  melissa : TTY=tty2 ; PWD=/home/melissa ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install pastebinit
Jun 21 13:38:30 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by melissa(uid=1000)
Jun 21 13:38:32 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 21 13:38:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo:  melissa : TTY=tty2 ; PWD=/home/melissa ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get -f install pastebinit
Jun 21 13:38:51 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by melissa(uid=1000)
Jun 21 13:38:52 melissa-ThinkPad-T430 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Here is lightdm.log:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.3, UID=0 PID=1085
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+0.00s] DEBUG: X server :0 will replace Plymouth
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Launching process 1094: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+3.55s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1094
[+3.55s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+3.55s] DEBUG: Stopping Plymouth, X server is ready
[+3.57s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+3.58s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+3.58s] DEBUG: Started session 1182 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+5.24s] DEBUG: Session 1182 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+5.24s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+5.24s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+5.30s] DEBUG: Session 1182 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+8.79s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.3
[+8.79s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
[+8.79s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+8.79s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+13.26s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for melissa
[+13.26s] DEBUG: Started session 1708 with service 'lightdm', username 'melissa'
[+13.28s] DEBUG: Session 1708 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+13.28s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+20.58s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Session 1708 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user melissa: Success
[+20.59s] DEBUG: User melissa authorized
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session ubuntu-2d
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Using session ubuntu-2d
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter
[+20.59s] DEBUG: Session 1182: Sending SIGTERM
[+20.70s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+20.70s] DEBUG: Session 1182 exited with return value 0
[+20.70s] DEBUG: Greeter quit
[+20.71s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+20.71s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+20.71s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+20.71s] DEBUG: Writing /home/melissa/.dmrc
[+20.75s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+20.82s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu-2d as user melissa
[+20.82s] DEBUG: Session 1708 running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
[+20.85s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+21.07s] DEBUG: Session 1708 exited with return value 0
[+21.07s] DEBUG: User session quit
[+21.07s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+21.07s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1094
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Process 1094 exited with return value 0
[+21.22s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Active display stopped, switching to greeter
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Switching to greeter
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Launching process 1919: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+21.22s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+21.29s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1919
[+21.29s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+21.29s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+21.29s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+21.29s] DEBUG: Started session 1924 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+21.30s] DEBUG: Session 1924 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+21.30s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+21.30s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+21.30s] DEBUG: Session 1924 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+21.39s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.3
[+21.39s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
[+21.39s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+21.39s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+21.39s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter display being switched from
[+21.63s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for melissa
[+21.63s] DEBUG: Started session 1998 with service 'lightdm', username 'melissa'
[+21.63s] DEBUG: Session 1998 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+21.63s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

Comment: Send us auth log and lightdm log

Comment: I edited the post with auth.log and lightdm.log.

Comment: Try to use different desktop envrinoment. Instead of GNOME 2D, use Unity, or something like this.

Comment: What happens when you try to log in using the Guest account?

Answer (score 0):

Please press Ctrl+Alt+F3 buttons and login with your username and password.
In the login prompt give: startx
You will be getting a Graphical user interface now.
Then disable automatic login for your account. Then create new user account,if you need. Keep automatic login disabled.

This may be the temporary solution. But this way you can make your os usable.